# Window FontSize is not inherited in child control

Tags: wpf, inheritance, window, font-size

In certain cases I have the problem that the `FontSize` that I set on a WPF window is not inherited to a child control.
It happens, if a custom user control sets its content (e.g. a `Label`) upon changing the `DataContext`.

I can reproduce this when putting this `UserControl` into a new window, then close this window and create a new one having the same `UserControl` in it (see the following code).

In my complex application it's a custom popup window and a custom `UserControl` that changes its content if the `DataContext` is changed. There the font is not inherited upon the *first* open of the window (so the usercontrol hasn't been in another visual/logical tree until that) but I can't reproduce this in a small test application.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    // App.xaml: ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var testControl = new TestControl();
        var w = new Window();
        w.FontSize = 40;
        w.DataContext = this;
        w.Content = testControl; // TestControl.DataContextChanged creates label which has FontSize = 40
        w.Show();

        w.Close();
        w.DataContext = null;
        //w.Content = null; // if this is done, the font will be correct (40)
        w = null;

        w = new Window();
        w.FontSize = 40;
        w.DataContext = this;
        //testControl.DataContext = this; // if this is done, the font will be correct (40)
        w.Content = testControl; // TestControl.DataContextChanged creates label with remaining FontSize = 12 (Default)
        w.Show();
    }
}

public class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public TestControl()
    {
        DataContextChanged += TestControl_DataContextChanged;
    }

    private void TestControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null) Content = new Label() { Content = "TestControllabel"};
        else Content = null;
    }
}
```

I'm not looking for a fix of this example app, but for the reason **why** the font size is not inherited in this special case, so maybe then I can fix my complex app.
Any thoughts would be useful !

**Edit**: For now I fixed my application by setting the datacontext of the control before setting it as window content.